# Update column with NaN with mean of filtered rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame

```
VOTES    CITY
 24      A
 22      A
 20      B
 NaN     A
 NaN     A
 30      B
 NaN     C
```

I need to fill the NaN with mean of values where CITY is 'A' or 'C'

The following code I tried was only updating the first row in VOTES and rest allwere updated to NaN.

```
train['VOTES'][((train['VOTES'].isna()) & (train['CITY'].isin(['A','C'])))]=train['VOTES'].loc[((~train['VOTES'].isna()) & (train['CITY'].isin(['A','C'])))].astype(int).mean(axis=0)
```

The output of 'VOTES' after this all values are updated as 'NaN' except one record which is at index 0. The Mean is calculated correctly though .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) only for filtered rows with mean of filtered rows:

```
train['VOTES_EN']=train['VOTES'].astype(str).str.extract(r'(-?\d+\.?\d*)').astype(float)
m= train['CITY'].isin(['A','C'])
mean = train.loc[m,'VOTES_EN'].mean() 
train.loc[m,'VOTES_EN']=train.loc[m,'VOTES_EN'].fillna(mean)
train['VOTES_EN'] = train['VOTES_EN'].astype(int)
print (train)
   VOTES CITY  VOTES_EN
0   24.0    A        24
1   22.0    A        22
2   20.0    B        20
3    NaN    A        23
4    NaN    A        23
5   30.0    B        30
6    NaN    C        23
```

Comment: I'm getting 'cannot index multidimensional key' . Just  to add 'VOTES' is a categorical column. Possible to create a new column?

Comment: Sorry , but still the same issue , the first line is to extract the numeric from the string variables , actually the column is having values i.e '24 votes' , hence extracted the same and assigned to new column .

     train['VOTES_EN']=train['VOTES'].astype(str).str.extract(r'(-?\d+\.?\d*)')
     m=train.loc[(train['CITY'].isin(['A','C']))]
     mean = train.loc[m,'VOTES_EN'].astype(int).mean()
     train.loc[m,'VOTES_EN']=train[m,'VOTES_EN'].fillna(mean)

Comment: @Alfaromeo - What is `print (train.info())` ?

Comment: `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

RangeIndex: 12690 entries, 0 to 12689

Data columns (total 10 columns):
TITLE            12690 non-null category

RESTAURANT_ID    12690 non-null int16

CUISINES         12690 non-null category

TIME             12690 non-null category

CITY             12578 non-null category

LOCALITY         12592 non-null category

RATING           12688 non-null category

VOTES            11486 non-null category

COST             12690 non-null int16

VOTES_EN         11486 non-null object

dtypes: category(7), int16(2), object(1)`

Comment: @Alfaromeo - There is main problem in `m=train.loc[(train['CITY'].isin(['A','C']))]` - need `m= train['CITY'].isin(['A','C'])`. Last not 100% sure if need last `train['VOTES_EN'] = train['VOTES_EN'].astype(int)`, because `mean` should in another data return floats, not integers.

Comment: `train['VOTES_EN']=train['VOTES'].astype(str).str.extract(r'(-?\d+\.?\d*)')
  m=train['CITY'].isin(['A','C])
  train['VOTES_EN'] = pd.to_numeric(train['VOTES_EN'])
  mean = train.loc[m,'VOTES_EN'].mean()
  print (mean)
  train.loc[m,'VOTES_EN']=train[m,'VOTES_EN'].fillna(mean)`

The last line now throws the error as "'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed"

Comment: @Alfaromeo You forget cast to float in first row `train['VOTES_EN']=train['VOTES'].astype(str).str.extract(r'(-?\d+\.?\d*)').astype(float)`

Comment: @Alfaromeo - In last line is lost second `loc` - need `train.loc[m,'VOTES_EN']=train.loc[m,'VOTES_EN'].fillna(mean)`

Comment: @Alfaromeo - Supeeeeeeeeeeeeer :) I am really happy :)